# How do I escape parenthesis in jQuery's :contains selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried to search for a user-agent string in a table using jQuery. If I search like this it is not found:

```
jQuery("table.make-html-table
td:contains('Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)')")
.css("background","yellow");
```

If I search like this - slashes before \( - then it give me an error:

```
jQuery("table.make-html-table
td:contains('Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)')")
.css("background","yellow");
```

Error:

```
"Syntax error, unrecognized expression: (comp...
```

How can I properly escape that string so that I can search for cells that contain it with jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant part in [sizzle](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/sizzle.js) is

```
PSEUDO: /:((?:[\w\u00c0-\uFFFF\-]|\\.)+)(?:\((['"]?)((?:\([^\)]+\)|[^\(\)]*)+)\2\))?/
```

which makes me think there is no way. Looks like it only accepts arguments that contain no parenthesis at all, or only one level thereof like `:contains("(foo)")`. An obvious improvement would be accept anything if an argument is quoted, hope this will be fixed soon.

For the time being, a workaround would be to write a selector that would accept escaped arguments, for example:

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
    containsEscaped: function (el, index, m) {  
        var s = unescape(m[3]);
        return $(el).text().indexOf(s) >= 0;
    }  
});
```

usage:

```
var p = $("p:containsEscaped('foo%28bar')");
```

In action: http://jsfiddle.net/9wWP5/

Comment: tested and working well. thank you! note to others - i used php's `rawurlescape` function to escape the user agent string that i was searching for.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Use two slashes:</strike>

```
jQuery("table.make-html-table
td:contains('Mozilla/4.0 \\(compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1\\)')")
.css("background","yellow");
```

Alternate solution:

```
jQuery("table.make-html-table td:contains('Mozilla/4.0'):contains('compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1')").css('background-color','yellow');
```

Another solution using textEquals custom selector

```
jQuery.expr[':'].textEquals = function(a, i, m) {
    return jQuery(a).text() === m[3];
};

...

jQuery("table.make-html-table td:textEquals('Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)')")
    .css("background","yellow");
```

Comment: had already tried that - forgot to mention it does not seem to work.

Comment: You are right. I'll post an alternate solution, thg435's answer has information as to why it doesn't work.

Comment: only problem with your alternate is that i'm getting the string passed in as a variable and so i'd need a way to dynamically find it.

Comment: There is a textEquals selector that you could use: